# sort data of text file and write it into another text file in c#

Tags: c#

i want to sort data from text file and save it on to another text file

here is my text file "employee.txt" i want to sort data using the "Employee code"

Employee code:107
First Name:swapnil
Last Name:dehjhja
Phone NO:6727672

---

Employee code:106
First Name:fhsgbf
Last Name:dehjhja
Phone NO:909888

---

Employee code:102
First Name:xyz
Last Name:dehjhja
Phone NO:098778

---

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the reading/writing of your files, you could simply use [File.ReadAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1.aspx) to read the lines into a string array and [File.WriteAllLines](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3.aspx) to write them back to a file.  These functions will handle all of the opening/closing of the files so that you don't have to.

To handle the sorting, we can use the [orderby keyword](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/92e05ft3.aspx) in LINQ and a static helper function `GetEmployeeCode` to get the EmployeeCode.  We can define our helper function as follows:

```
public static int GetEmployeeCode(string line)
{
    // Get the substring starting after "Employee code:"
    // ... and stopping at the first space.
    string employeeCode = line.Substring(14).Split(' ')[0];
    int code;
    Int32.TryParse(employeeCode, out code);
    return code;
}
```

The following code will then sort all of the lines in your file in ascending order by EmployeeCode and then write them to a new file:

```
string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines(@"C:\original.txt");

// Sort the rows in lines by EmployeeCode
lines = (from line in lines
        orderby GetEmployeeCode(line) ascending
        select line).ToArray();

File.WriteAllLines(@"C:\sorted.txt", lines);
```

Comment: Works only if all codes are three-digit. Otherwise, employee `22` would get placed *after* employee `111`.

Comment: Good point...  I'll update the above to take that into account.

Answer (score 1):

You need to import your data into sortable entities, call the sort method on your collection (i.e. `List<T>`) then export the data into whatever format you want.

For the import/export stuff, I recommend FileHelpers lib http://www.filehelpers.com/downloads.html

For the sorting stuff, implement `IComparable<>` on your entity.

Example for ICompable:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
public class Person : IComparable<Person>
{
    #region Private Members
    private string _firstname;
    private string _lastname;
    private int _age;
    #endregion
    #region Properties
    public string Firstname
    {
        get { return _firstname; }
        set { _firstname = value; }
    }
    public string Lastname
    {
        get { return _lastname; }
        set { _lastname = value; }
    }
    public int Age
    {
        get { return _age; }
        set { _age = value; }
    }
    #endregion
    #region Contructors
    public Person (string firstname, string lastname, int age)
    {
        _firstname = firstname;
        _lastname = lastname;
        _age = age;
    }
    #endregion
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return String.Format(“{0} {1}, Age = {2}“, _firstname,
             _lastname, _age.ToString());
    }
    #region IComparable Members
    public int CompareTo(Person obj)
    {
        return _firstname.CompareTo(p2.Firstname);
    }
    #endregion
}
```